# iFrame resize problem in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have made a script to reseize an iFrame to the height of its content. It works like a charm, but not in IE. IE gives me the size i have set in CSS for the iframe. Any idea how i could fix this?

```
function iFramler($iFrames, $){
  if($iFrames.length){

        var resizeiFrame = function($iFrame){
           console.log($iFrame.contents().find("body").height()) 
               //gives back the iFrame height in IE not the height of the content :(

           $iFrame.height( $iFrame.contents().find("body").height() + 40 );
        };

        $iFrames.each(function(){
          var $that = $(this);
          $that.load(function(){
            resizeiFrame($that);
          });
        });
  }else{
       return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `$iFrame.contents().find('body')[0].scrollHeight`? It should be a DOMElement property, not an attribute.

Comment: i get Error: 'contents().find(...).0.scrollHeight' is null or not an object in IE

Comment: @timdream you solution showd me the right path. it worked with `$iFrame[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` if you post an answer with this i give ou the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$iFrame[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` works. `scrollHeight` should be a DOMElement property, not an attribute.